# Module build failed (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js) when adding Nuxt SSR into vue 2

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js):                                                                                                                                                                                                                           friendly-errors 15:42:31
TypeError: Cannot read property 'styles' of undefined
    at Object.loader (/home/<name>/Documents/<project>/node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js:70:34)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              friendly-errors 15:42:31
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js 26:0-52 312:0-32
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/eventsource-polyfill/dist/browserify-eventsource.js ./node_modules/webpack-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&timeout=30000&ansiColors=&overlayStyles=&path=%2F__webpack_hmr%2Fclient&name=client ./.nuxt/client.js
```

I spend a lot of time for this error. What should I do?

edit:
I just want to add nuxt ssr into an existing vue 2 project. I just ran into this problem.

Here are some information:

This is the error page I get:
[error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ne00m.png)

this is package.json dependencies

```
"@nuxt/core": "^2.15.7",
"@nuxtjs/robots": "^2.5.0",
"@nuxtjs/sitemap": "^2.4.0",
"axios": "^0.21.1",
"bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
"bootstrap-vue": "^2.23.1",
"core-js": "^3.6.5",
"emittery": "^0.11.0",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"firebase": "^7.17.1",
"jspdf": "^2.5.1",
"jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.25",
"moment": "^2.27.0",
"moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
"node-sass": "^7.0.1",
"nuxt": "^2.15.7",
"nuxt-start": "^2.15.8",
"on-screen-keyboard-detector": "^2.3.0",
"raw-loader": "^4.0.2",
"register-service-worker": "^1.7.1",
"string-format-validation": "^2.0.2",
"sweetalert": "^2.1.2",
"v-calendar": "^2.4.1",
"validator": "^13.1.1",
"vue": "^2.7.5",
"vue-barcode-reader": "^0.0.3",
"vue-directive-long-press": "^1.1.0",
"vue-form-generator": "^2.3.4",
"vue-i18n": "^8.22.0",
"vue-js-toggle-button": "^1.3.3",
"vue-material-design-ripple": "^1.0.0",
"vue-meta": "^2.4.0",
"vue-qrcode-reader": "^3.0.1",
"vue-router": "^3.1.6",
"vue-select": "^3.11.2",
"vue-server-renderer": "2.7.14",
"vue-simple-alert": "^1.1.1",
"vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
"vuejs-datepicker": "^1.6.2",
"vuex": "^3.2.0"
```

I have tried deleting `node_modules` folder and run `yarn install` but still not fixed

Comment: Pretty hard to help without a [repro] or any given details as of your configuration. Showing us 2 lines of error will not help us at all here unfortunately.

Comment: Hey, This is my first question. I'm going to post more info

Comment: You don't have `sass` in your dependencies list. Use `sass` instead of `node-sass`. This may or may not fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you, I just removed `node-sass` and added `sass@^1.56.1` , then I did rebuild. It didn't seem to fix it. I see same error on the web page. It seems that it did nothing to the code.

Comment: I recommend creating a Nuxt2 app and moving things into it overall. Rather than the opposite, especially since some packages will be already built-in.